# Reading inbox from a specific sender and for a specific subject in order to save excel attachments

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my .net core console application, I am reading a mail inbox and saving excel attachments from a specific sender that has a specific subject. It is working as is expected, I wonder if there are any improvements to make it better. So I would be glad if you can share your comments.

Thanks in advance.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var client = new ImapClient();
            client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);

            client.Authenticate("test@gmail.com", "12345");

            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

            
            var query = SearchQuery.FromContains("test@gmail.com")
                .And(SearchQuery.SubjectContains("101")).And(SearchQuery.NotSeen);

            foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(query))
            {
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);

                foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
                {
                    if (attachment is MessagePart)
                    {
                        var fileName = attachment.ContentDisposition?.FileName;
                        var rfc822 = (MessagePart)attachment;

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                            fileName = "attached-message.eml";

                        using var stream = File.Create(fileName);
                        rfc822.Message.WriteTo(stream);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var part = (MimePart)attachment;
                        var fileName = part.FileName;
                        var file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
                        var newPath = fileName.Replace(file, file + "-"+ uid);
                        Console.WriteLine(newPath);
                        Console.WriteLine(uid);
                        using var stream = File.Create(newPath);
                        part.Content.DecodeTo(stream);
                    }

                    inbox.AddFlags(uid, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
                    
                }

 
            }
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want your code to be compacted?

Comment: may be more maintainable :)

Comment: Which version of C# are you using?

Comment: I am using VS 2019, latest version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintainability can mean different things for different developers. Here I will use [this website](https://www.brcline.com/blog/5-tips-write-maintainable-code)'s definition:

> Maintainable code is basically
> the amount of time it takes a developer to make a change and  
> the amount of risk that the change could break something.

So from this perspective a *not maintainable* code means:

- either there is lots of effort to make changes
- or there is a high probability to break something

---

What sort of changes can you expect?

- Be able to connect to other user's mailbox
- Be able read not just inbox, but other folders as well
- Be able to retrieve other messages not just the not seen ones

Any of the above changes requires **multiple** adjustments on your code. That means more effort and higher probability to break something.

Oneway to lower risk and minimize modification efforts is to

- **Group those things together which are semantically tight to each other**
- **Have some and well-focused reusable parts/components**
- **Use optional parameters with default values to make your code more flexible**

---

If you look at your code from 1000 feet high then you can see the following:

- Connect to a mailbox
- Select a folder
- Issue a search query
- Iterate through the messages
- Handle attachments based on their type

So, your `main` should follow this same level of abstraction:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    using var client = ConnectToMailbox();
    var folder = SelectFolder(client);
 
    foreach (var messageId in IssueSearch(folder))
    foreach (var attachment in folder.GetMessage(messageId).Attachments)
    {
        _ = attachment switch
        {
            MessagePart messagePart => HandleMessagePart(messagePart),
            MimePart mimePart => HandleMimePart(mimePart, messageId),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Attachment is unknown")
        };
 
        folder.AddFlags(messageId, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
    }
}
```

Each of the methods are well focused and have small responsibilities. So, any of the above changes are localized (*there is a single and easy spot place to do adjustments*).

#### Connect to a mailbox

```
 ImapClient ConnectToMailbox(
    string host = "imap.gmail.com", int port = 993, bool useSsl = true,
    string username = "test@gmail.com", string pwd = "12345")
{
    var client = new ImapClient();
    client.Connect(host, port, useSsl);
    client.Authenticate(username, pwd);
    return client;
}
```

#### Select a folder

```
IMailFolder SelectFolder(ImapClient client, SpecialFolder? folder = null)
{
    var inbox = folder.HasValue ? client.GetFolder(folder.Value): client.Inbox;
    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
    return inbox;
}
```

#### Issue a search query

```
IList<UniqueId> IssueSearch(IMailFolder inbox,
    string from = "test@gmail.com",
    string subject = "101",
    SearchQuery? filter = null)
{
    var query = SearchQuery.FromContains(from)
        .And(SearchQuery.SubjectContains(subject))
        .And(filter ?? SearchQuery.NotSeen);
    return inbox.Search(query);
}
```

#### Handle attachments based on their type

```
MimeEntity HandleMessagePart(MessagePart attachment)
{
    var fileName = attachment.ContentDisposition?.FileName;
 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        fileName = "attached-message.eml";
 
    using var stream = File.Create(fileName);
    attachment.Message.WriteTo(stream);
    return attachment;
}

MimeEntity HandleMimePart(MimePart attachment, UniqueId uid)
{
    var fileName = attachment.FileName;
    var file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    var newPath = fileName.Replace(file, $"{file}-{uid}");
    Console.WriteLine(newPath);
    Console.WriteLine(uid);
 
    using var stream = File.Create(newPath);
    attachment.Content.DecodeTo(stream);
    return attachment;
}
```

Comment: The double `foreach` and `_` for the `switch` hacks are nice haha :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t I do agree it is not the nicest code that I've ever written, but at least it is concise :D